# Python Script, tesseract. No error but no output

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to use `tesseract` to read text from an image, i have installed `tesseract` using home brew but i get no output. Here is my code;

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image    
    
value = Image.open('/Users/director/Desktop/databoy/easytt.jpeg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(value, lang="eng")
print(text)
```

I don't get any errors, and it does not print out anything, i just get:
`Process finished with exit code 0`

[image: This is the image i was working with]

Comment: I have edited my initial post by adding a link to the image, thank you and i look forward to receiving from you.

Comment: Do you think it’s possible that your Captcha image has been designed so it isn’t recognisable as characters when naively scanned with OCR/Tesseract?

Comment: well esyocr works perfectly with thesame Captcha image

Comment: Did you know that before you asked your question? Anyway, great, go for it.

Comment: no i did not know that. i tried easyocr just before my question was answered, also this answer came in handy today cause i referred it to someone who had the same problem.

Comment: @director What was the solution to the problem?

Comment: @MariaSheikh i am very sorry for the late reply, i have not been active for a while. But for the solution i had to use EasyOCR instead. It was way easier.